# `instance_eval` and scopes

Tags: ruby, eval, instance-eval

I have the following code:

```
class A
  def self.scope
    yield
  end
  def self.method_added method
    self.instance_eval %{
      # do something involving the added method 
    }
  end
end

class B < A
  scope do 
    def foo
    end
  end
end
```

When the `method_added` hook is fired, will the code inside `instance_eval` run within the same scope as the method that was added? Or, will it run outside of it?

What are the caveats and gotchas involved within this?

Comment: hmm My issue is partially solved, still I would like to know what people have to say any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scope` method is basically a no-op. When you pass a block to a method that yields, the block is evaluated in the *current* scope. Observe:

```
class A
  def self.scope
    yield
  end
end

A.scope { p self }
# main
```

Since nothing is yielded to the block, and nothing is done with the return value of `yield`, any code run in the block will have the same effect run outside the `scope` block.

This isn't the case with `instance_eval`, however. When `instance_eval` runs a block, `self` in the block is set to the receiver (rather than whatever `self` is in the block's scope). Like this:

```
class A
end

A.instance_eval { p self }
# A
```

But note that this means that `self.instance_eval { ... }` is also a fancy no-op, because you're changing the block's `self` to the same `self` outside the block.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
class A
  def self.method_added method
    # do something involving the added method 
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
  end
end
```

Comment: what does 'no-op' mean?

Comment: It's short for "no operation", meaning a programming instruction which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find out!

```
class A
  def self.scope
    yield
  end
  def self.method_added method
    puts "In method_added, method = #{method}, self = #{self}" 
    instance_eval 'puts "In instance_eval, method = #{method}, self = #{self}"'
  end
end

class B < A
  scope do
    puts "In scope's block, self = #{self}" 
    def foo
    end
  end
end

  # In scope's block, self = B
  # In method_added, method = foo, self = B
  # In instance_eval, method = foo, self = B
```

Notice that you don't need `self.` in `self.instance_eval`.